# Well ordered sets, set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define a relation $R$ among ordered pairs of ordinals by $(\gamma,\delta)R(\lambda,\kappa)$ if $\gamma +\delta<\lambda +\kappa$ or $\gamma +\delta=\lambda +\kappa$ and $\gamma<\lambda$

(1) Prove that this is a well-order in  the class of ordered pairs of ordinals and that for every $(\lambda,\kappa)$ the class $\{(\gamma,\delta): (\gamma,\delta)R(\lambda,\kappa)\}$ is a set.

First we have to show that it is a strict linear order, i.e., $R$ is irreflexive, transitive and linear relation, and after that the wellfoundedness part of finding the least element.

How can I show the wellfoundness part?
And to prove that it is a set, what shall I use? Replacement? 
Thanks for any help, I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: Something's wrong. $(5,6) R (3,\omega)$ since $5+6 = 11 < \omega = 3+\omega$. But $(3,\omega) R (5,6)$ since $3 < 5$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Could it be that \gamma +\delta<\lambda +\kappa or \gamma +\delta=\lambda +\kappa and \gamma<\lambda ?

Comment: @user160628: That was probably the intention, that if the first case (sum comparison) fails then the second case should hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$ for $i\in \omega$ is an infinite descending chain. Now suppose infinitely often that $\alpha_i + \beta_i > \alpha_{i+1} + \beta_{i+1}$. If this is the case the ordinals $\gamma_i := \alpha_i + \beta_i$ form an infinite descending chain contradicting the well-foundedness of ORD.

So there is a $n$ such that for all $m>n$ $\alpha_m + \beta_{m} = \alpha_{m+1} + \beta_{m+1}$. Therefore for all $m>n$, $\alpha_i > \alpha_{i+1}$, forming an infinite descending chain in ORD.